# fetch time from google direction api and add it to another time in ios swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-api, swift3

I want to fetch time from google direction api with some waypoints in it and need to show the time the bus will reach at those way points. here is my code:

```
func requestPlaces()
{
    let url = NSString (format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?   origin=%@&waypoints=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false&mode=DRIVING",    busLatLong, wayPointsLatLong, destinationLatLong)

    let  urlString:String = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    print(urlString, terminator: "")

    let url1 = URL.init(string: urlString)

    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url1!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync
            {

            }
            return
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        {
            //print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if statusCode == 200
            {
                do
                {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    print(jsonResult)

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync
                    {
                        if (jsonResult.value(forKey: "status") as! String == "OK")
                        {
                            if let routes = jsonResult.value(forKey: "routes") as? NSArray
                            {
                                if let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs") as? NSArray
                                {
                                    if let duration = legs.value(forKey: "duration") as? NSArray
                                    {
                                        for i in 0..<duration.count
                                        {
                                            let timeDuration = duration[i] as! NSArray

                                            if let time = timeDuration.value(forKey: "value") as? NSArray
                                            {
                                                self.timeArray = time as! [Int]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            print(self.timeArray)
                            self.gmsMap.delegate = self
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError
                {
                    print(error)
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

from here I am fetching the value and the remaining time to reach to that location.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let dates = dateFormatter.date(from: self.getBusStartTime)
    print("dates\(dates)")

    let components = self.getBusStartTime.characters.split { $0 == ":" } .map { (x) -> Int in return Int(String(x))! }

    let hours = components[0]
    let minutes = components[1]

    let hoursSec = hours * 3600
    let MintueSS = minutes * 60
    let ConvertInSeconds = hoursSec + MintueSS

    for i in 0..<self.getBusTimeArray.count
    {
        let totalSec =  ConvertInSeconds + self.getBusTimeArray[i]

        let SubSec = totalSec - ConvertInSeconds
        let FinalConvert = (SubSec / 3600, (SubSec % 3600) / 60, (SubSec % 3600) % 60)
        print("convert FinalConvert\(FinalConvert)")

        let StrHours: Float = Float(FinalConvert.0)
        let StrMins: Float = Float(FinalConvert.1)

        print(StrHours)
        print(StrMins)
    }'
```

This code is giving me the time difference between the starting position and the way points.Now my issue is that I want the time in this format say 11:40, time to reach at first point 11: 50, time to reach at second point. With the above code I can findout their difference like 3 min, 10 min etc. I don't know how to achieve what I want. Any help.'